# VBA Find and Replace within a For loop not replacing as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm taking Excel worksheets and putting them into XML format, to then import to SQL. I have a worksheet of a list of file links, called "Files List". The code opens up the necessary sheet within the file links and puts the data into a sheet called "XML format", which is suitable to then import to SQL. The issue is that the Find and Replace within the loop of transferring the data does run, but not seem to get passed the first "Files List" reference.

```
Sub LinkFile()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files List").Activate

oldfile = Sheets("Files List").Range("oldFile")

Debug.Print oldfile
strfnd = oldfile
Set db1 = connect_sql_server()

strfnd = Format_link(oldfile)
Debug.Print strfnd

For i = 3 To 50

Sheets("Files List").Range("FIleIndex").value = i

filelink = Sheets("Files List").Range("fileindex2")

curfile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files List").Range("curfile")

Set wkbkNew = Workbooks.Open(filelink)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XML Format").Range("B3") = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Debug.Print (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XML Format").Range("B3"))

Set wbsheet = wkbkNew.Sheets("Calculations")

    filelink = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files List").Range("E3")


    strRplc = filelink
    Debug.Print (strRplc)
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XML Format")
    Application.Volatile

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.Volatile

     sht.Cells.Replace What:=strfnd, Replacement:=strRplc, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
         SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        strfnd = strRplc
        Debug.Print (strfnd)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XML Format").Activate
    strxml = concatenate_xml()
    Debug.Print (strxml)
     'this imports data into sql server
     WriteDB strxml, db1

strfnd = strRplc
continue:
Next i

db1.Close
End Sub
```

Say the loop is set as i=2 to 2. The expected result is that in the "XML Format" sheet, the data should be from the second files link in "Files List". The actual output is that the data is always from the first files link, the original "oldfile". The only thing that works as expected is the file name, "ActiveWorkbook.Name".

Comment: Did yo umean it doesn't get past `Sheets("Files List").Range("FIleIndex").value = i` ?

Comment: Is this all the code? because some things just don't make sense... Do you have  Tables (Named Ranges) called: `oldFile`, `FIleIndex`, `fileindex2`, `curfile` ?

Comment: As far as I can see all you do with i (the iteration number of your loop) is write it away on the "File list" tab. It then never gets called again, so the loop has no way of knowing in which iteration it is, and will repeat the same exact first loop until it has counted to 50.

Comment: Whenever you are assigning a Range to a Variable, that line of code has to start by `Set`, so for example very early on `oldfile = Sheets("Files List").Range("oldFile")` should be `Set oldfile = Sheets("Files List").Range("oldFile")`, and all the other Range assignment should have Set in front of the Reference Variable.

Comment: Yeah sorry, oldFile, FIleIndex, fileindex2, curfile are cell references within "Files List". FIleIndex is the number of the the file link down the list, and fileindex2 is the corresponding file link. oldfile is intitially the first file link in the files list, and curfile initially the second link. As it goes through the For loop, the oldfile should become the second link (the then current file) and curfile becomes the next one along, so the third file link in the first instance and so on

Comment: The FIleIndex also changes the curfile to be the current file link i.e. fileindex2 and curfile will be the same file link.

Comment: Additionally they are all Variants, hence why no Set for the oldfile.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I cannot spend a lot of time answering your problem in detail. Trying to work though loads of cells in Excel in various workbooks generally gave me a lot of issues. Especially if you have macros running on worksheet events. The best advice I can give is that you get the full range from the old worksheet, process it with VBA, and then put it back into the new worksheet. It will also speed up your macro by orders of magnitude.

the process will then look a bit like this:

```
XML_table = thisWorkbook.range()

for i = 1 to nr_rows
   for j = 1 to nr_columns
      XML_table(i,j) = replace_str(XML_table(i,j))
    next j
next i

thatWorkbook.range() = XML_table
```

good luck, hope the quick advice helped a bit

Comment: Is XML_table referring to my "XML Format" sheet?

Comment: Yes. XML_table is just a name for the range that you want to evaluate

Comment: I believe the main issue is regarding the find and replace, more specifically strfnd and strRplc

Comment: Nope, currently working on a separate module which focuses just on the link swap using the find and replace, will definitely consider it though! Appreciate the help.

Comment: How would you construct the 2nd and 3rd arguments in a loop, because the new text becomes the old text then the next one on the list becomes the new text etc. Do they have to be specific bits of text or can you reference cells like in the 1st argument?

Comment: Hi Rob. Not quite sure what youre asking. Substitute replaces portions of text. If you run substitute("apples","app","bang") you should get "bangles". So in the code i had above use the substitute function in the place of the replace_str holder i had there. You can pass XML_table(i,j) to substitute() to reassign the value.

Comment: I'm running a loop, and in the "curfile" and "oldfile" cells, the text (file links) changes as each iteration of the loop runs, so I'm not sure it would work

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret this correctly (which is kind of tough since you use a lot of named ranges which I have no way of knowing where they link to) you do not account for iterations of your loop. You write away the iteration number on tab "Files list" and that's it. This means since you use absolute references for everything, it will repeat all steps exactly as you wrote them for the first iteration, never progressing. You need to feed `i` back into your loop as a row number to advance to the second row like so:

```
filelink = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files List").Range("E" & i)
```

Which from `i = 3` to `i = 50` actually loops through rows 3 to 50 in your "Files list" sheet, rather than taking "E3" every time.

Comment: Cell E3 is the curfile cell (I've recently referenced in the comments section above), so as the loop runs, the file link in the cell changes to the current file in the loop.

Comment: That's my bad for not putting enough of the relevant info

Comment: In that case my answer would be irrelevant, apologies for that. I'll delete it in a moment. As for the actual problem, I'm afraid you have me at a loss as well.

Comment: No worries, I definitely did not make it clear. Thanks for trying to help, much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you could get an answer quicker with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As I tried running it for myself and got stuck trying to recreate your whole file. Trying to do so is also a great way to narrow down the problem and debug for yourself as well.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how I can do that unfortunately